# Error upgrading to Mongo 4.0, I am getting typescript error while trying to upgrade

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to upgrade mongodb from 3.4 to 4.0. I am using angularjs.
typescript version - 3.5.1
angular version - 1.5.8
mongoose version - 5.12.1

I am getting typescript-errors. In all the files that have similar implementation.

```
 error TS2344: Type 'DExperience' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<any, {}>'.
  Types of property 'model' are incompatible.
    Type '{ <T extends Model<any, {}>>(name: string): T; (name: string): Model<DExperience, {}>; }' is not assignable to type '{ <T extends Model<any, {}>>(name: string): T; (name: string): Model<Document<any, {}>, {}>; }'.
```

this is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "api-server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8",
    "bcrypt": "3.0.6",
    "body-parser": "1.13.3",
    "cloudinary": "^1.4.3",
    "co": "4.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "4.13.3",
    "mongoose": "5.12.1",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "node-schedule": "^1.2.5",
    "sequelize": "5.10.1",
    "standard-error": "1.1.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
    "@types/angular": "^1.5.20",
    "@types/angular-route": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/body-parser": "1.19.0",
    "@types/debug": "0.0.29",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.34",
    "@types/http-status": "^0.2.29",
    "@types/jade": "0.0.29",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.1",
    "@types/js-yaml": "3.12.5",
    "@types/jwt-simple": "^0.5.32",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.40",
    "@types/mongoose": "5.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
    "@types/node-schedule": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/pluralize": "0.0.27",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.4",
    "acquit": "0.4.0",
    "acquit-ignore": "0.0.3",
    "acquit-markdown": "0.0.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "^0.10.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "detect-port": "^1.0.6",
    "dookie": "0.4.1",
    "ts-loader": "4.3.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.7.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.1",
    "webpack": "4.44.1",
  },
```

type of RawVendor, RawExperience, Dvendor and DExperience

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { DDatabaseInstance, RawDatabaseInstance } from './database-instance';

export interface RawVendor {
  name?: string;
  description?: string;
  createdBy?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId | string;
  url?: string;
  city?: string;
  isVisible?: boolean;
}
export interface RawExperience {
  name?: string;
  vendor?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId | string;
  description?: string;
  vendorName?: string;
  order?: number;
}

export interface DVendor extends DDatabaseInstance, RawVendor {
  validateSync: (paths?: string[]) => any;
}

export interface DExperience extends DDatabaseInstance, RawExperience {
  validateSync: (paths?: string[]) => any;
}
```

Here is database-instance.ts

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Timestamps } from './timestamps';

/**
 * A wrapper type around raw hashes that will exist on either POJO database objects or on `mongoose.Document`s.
 */
export interface RawDatabaseInstance extends Timestamps {
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
}

/**
 * A wrapper type around a non-POJO `mongoose.Document`
 */
export interface DDatabaseInstance extends mongoose.Document {
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  id: string;

  get(path: string): any;
}
```

timestamp.ts

```
export interface Timestamps {
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

This is where I am getting error

```
export interface MVendor extends mongoose.Model<DVendor> {}

export interface MExperience extends mongoose.Model<DExperience> {}
```

Comment: Have you upgraded the `@types/mongodb` package as well? If you have done that already, then you may need to share your package.json and the code where the error occurs - otherwise it's difficult to help.

Comment: I've added the details, please let me know if there is anything more I need to add @cdimitroulas

Comment: Can you share the `DVendor` and `DExperience` types too?

Comment: I'm still not able to reproduce your code because it's not clear what the DDatabaseInstance type should be or where it comes from

Comment: In any case I'm not sure why you want to extend from `mongoose.Model`. You should just create a model the normal way that you would with mongoose in JS. If you want a more type-safe approach, I recommend looking at typegoose https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/